# how to set the size of the UIImage to be placed into a tableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

i have some UIImage's which i am supposed to place in a UITableView. The size of the images is not constant. It can be smaller than the tableview's cell or can even be bigger. This inconsistency in the image size is causing a lot of trouble for my tableView.

**Is there any way in which i can adjust the size of the UIImage so that it fits exactly to my tableView cell ???**

Comment: What kind of troubles does it causing? What behavior do you expect? I suppose row height is constant for all rows. Is the aspect of the images constant? Why don't you just set for all cells `cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`?

Comment: Do you use default UITableViewCell or your own? And what imageView do you use: default cell.imageView or create your own and place it on the cell?

Comment: i'm using the default tableView cell... i haven't subclassed it.

Comment: only part of the image is being visible if the image is big... this is the problem i'm facing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and rescale you `UIImage` so that it fits the row height. Have a look a the [`UIImage+SDSCategory.h`](https://github.com/sdesimone/iOSSnippets) category available on GitHub. Many people will tell you that images should not be scaled on iPhone/iPad due to performance reason and that this should be done on the server; when this is an option, it is the best option. But if you have no other option, then also scaling on iPhone/iPad can be fine.

Otherwise you could make your table view row higher, so that the UIImage fits into it naturally. Check the [`– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method in your delegate.